# Command macro for an environment

Tags: macros

How can I define a command macro using `\newcommand` so that the argument to the command is surrounded by an environment?

Comment: yes you can do that, what is the question?

Comment: It's possible but I doubt it to be very effective.

Comment: @David Ah my mistake, the code in my question wasn't working on my machine, but it was for an unrelated reason.

Comment: One should note that not all environments can be macro-ized in this way.  Sometimes, `\newcommand\mat[1]{\envname #1\endenvname}` must be used.  Sometimes, not even that works.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Apart from verbatim most can (including `align`)

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I know no environment that cannot be *fully* embedded in a new command; you're probably referring to defining new *environment* in terms of some specific ones such as `align`.

Comment: @egreg Even verbatim environments?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's of course an exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A proof that it is possible and using an optional argument that can be `b` or `p` or anything of the known prefixes (e.g. `v`, `B` and `V`)

Besides that all: It does not improve readability of the code, in my point of view.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\mat}[2][b]{%
  \begin{#1matrix}
    #2
  \end{#1matrix}
}

\begin{document}
$\mat{ 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\}$ and $ \mat[p]{ 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\}$ and $\mat[B]{ 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\}$ and $\mat[v]{ 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\}$ and $ \mat[V]{ 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4 \\}$
\end{document}
```

[image]